# make a query with conditions in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, model

i wanna get the reservations that their status aren't canceled or if status is canceled it check they have unread messages or not

Can you help me?

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
  public function unreadMessages() {
      return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'reservation_id', 'id')
               ->where('read', 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code which you tried

Comment: @JohnLobo i don't know how to write it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use where callback method

```
Reservation::where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('status','!=','canceled')
            ->orWhere(function ($query){
                $query->where('status','canceled')->whereHas('unreadMessages');
            });
    })->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$data = User::with(['unreadMessages'=> function($q){
            $q->where('read', 0);
        }])->get();
```

Remove the condition for the model and implement it in the way mentioned in the query.